# How to get Public Ip address of a remote system

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am Creating  a web site in VB.Net, I want to create a button for each post to vote my works (just like "like" button in fb). For this I must save the public ip of each user, and change the button text to "Unlike" on first click based on the ip address.

I need help and code suggestion to get the ip address of a remote machine.

supports are appreciated. thank you!

Comment: Have you tried looking it up?

Comment: This idea is not likely to work very well: more than one computer can have the same public IP address if they are behind a NAT router.

Comment: so if this idea not work..so how they create a like system in facebook ?

Comment: Facebook uses a user ID to uniquely identify each user. Notice how you have to log in to Facebook to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to a badly phrased question...

```
Current.Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
```

Comment: where can i use this code and how can i save the ip address in my sql server ?

Comment: you can use this line of code somewhere in your website and save the ip somewhere in your sql server. no offence ;P

Comment: LOL...if i know where, i never asking. so please help me...i need this.

Comment: Sorry, (as @chinz said, no offence), but if you need help with where to put a line of code and how to write to your own SQL database, then you should be reading books, not asking questions on here.